# How to customize WAR plugin in subproject in Gradle build script (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, gradle, war

I create a Gradle project with several sub-modules, and one module needs `war` plugin, I just want to customize the web app directory, but the code does not work:

```
apply {
    plugin("war")
    plugin("org.gretty")
}

// cannot work
tasks.getByName("war") {
    from("src/main/webfiles")
}

// cannot work either
tasks.war {
    webAppDirName = "src/main/webfiles"
}

//... other code
```

This is how I code in the sub-project `subproject.gradle.kts` file, How to solve this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: what do you mean by ""cannot work": do you have any error in logs ? in your subproject script you don't provide the `org.gretty` plugin version (version is required for non-core plugins), but maybe you have set the version in root project build with something like `plugins { id ("org.gretty") version "3.0.3" apply false } ` ?

Comment: @M.Ricciuti thanks for your comment, I really add `plugins { id ("org.gretty") version "3.0.3" apply false }` in my root project gradle build script, this is the sub-project script, now I solved the problem, the server works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the code:

```
configure<WarPluginConvention>{
    webAppDirName = "src/main/webfiles"
}
```